# Not Getting Debug Logs Even Though Not Guest User and Trace Flags Set

Tags: debugging, logging, debug

I have setup my User Trace Flags like I would normally as my current user, but for some reason no debug logs are being captured. It would be different if statements were missing in the log, but I am not getting a debug log at all. To be clear, when I mean there are no debug logs, I mean this: [image: No log at all]

It is as if the plafort is ignoring the trace flags altogether. Why would it do this all of a sudden?

The trace flags haven't expired. I tried both trace flags, still nothing with either of them.

[image] 
[image]
**Note: I am in central time, so I am an hour behind.**

Comment: Yes, I have seen that for the last few months (on many orgs, mainly newer ones). Only way to get the logs is to have dev console open. To be clear this is NOT related to the guest user logs requiring a cookies. Debug logs no longer show up in the UI for any trace flag. I opened a ticket a month or so ago and it got shut down with the typical redirect for the developer forums

Comment: Yes. Absolutely correct. It is not related to the guest user logs requiring cookies.

Comment: I even have the developer console open and it doesn't capture it. This is really aggravating.

Comment: I am not sure if it is related but it seems to be on orgs created within the last x months. I have a full sandbox org refreshed last year and logs still appear but almost all newer orgs they do not (for me and not sure if that is a true assumption)

Comment: Yes, I created this Sandbox a few days ago. I just wish I could find my issue I'm trying to capture and move on.

Comment: Are you sure the trace settings have not expired? Can you screenshot them for us?

Comment: Yeah I can do that.

Comment: Can uou Check you have selected correct user. Sometimes we have multiple user with same name

Comment: Yes, I have the correct user selected. We have a small user base and none of the users are the same.

Comment: @Eric I am still unable to get the debug to work, even with the developer console open. I will add, I am trying to debug an issue with an insert trigger messing up during a data loader operation. The only way I'd be able to test it is to move the code to Production and test it.

Comment: Sounds like you may need to open a case with SF

Comment: Speak of the devil. I just opened one.